display visitor counter for website using typescript
I want to ask how to add the number of visitors to my website. I've tried using the api from here https://countapi.xyz/ but now the server is down so it can't be used anymore. There is also an api from here https://count.cab/.How do I get count data from this api https://count.cab/hit/ghG6Oirn0b to my typescript try to browse but still don't know how i'm still new to typescript so please kindly explain in detail how to. Here the code there is no error message but the count not showing on my website
     type visitortype={
      count:number
    }
    
    const Footer = () => {
      const [visitor, setvisitor] = useState<visitortype>();
    }
    
     const getvisitor = async () => {
        try {
          await fetchRequest({
            method: 'GET',
            path: 'https://count.cab/hit/ghG6Oirn0b',
          }).then((response) => {
            setvisitor(response.visitor || []);
            
          });
        } catch (error) {}
      };

      useEffect(() => {
        getvisitor();
      }, []);

        <GridItem
          w="100%"
          h={{ base: '80px', lg: '300px' }}
          colSpan={{ base: 8, lg: 4 }}
        >
          <VStack
            align={{ base: 'center', lg: 'stretch' }}
            marginTop={{ base: '0', lg: '60px' }}
            marginLeft={{ base: '0', lg: '50px' }}
          >
            <Box w={{ base: '100px', lg: '220px' }} paddingBottom={'10px'}>
              <Image src={imgLogoMd} alt="Logo" w="100%" />
              <HStack>
              
              <Text
                fontSize={{ base: 'xs', lg: 'md' }}
                textAlign={'justify'}
              >
                {visitor?.count} Visitor
              </Text>
            </HStack>
          </VStack>
        
        </GridItem>


Share the code you wrote, and explain what how you got stuck.

@Evert add the code ,no error but the count not showing

I assume you are using React? I think you are still missing some key concepts here: You are creating a component (in your case a functional component), which can be used as building blocks within other components. However, it does not render HTML on its own.
So first, let's have a look at the component itself. It is important that hooks (like useEffect()) are called from inside your functional component, and that you return your JSX from there instead of having it just sit somewhere.
type visitortype = {
  count: number;
};

const Footer = () => {
  const [visitor, setvisitor] = useState<visitortype>();

  const getvisitor = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetchRequest({
        method: "GET",
        path: "https://count.cab/hit/ghG6Oirn0b",
      });
      // no need to use .then here, as you are already using await
      setvisitor(response.visitor || []);
    } catch (error) {
      // ensure you don't miss errors
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getvisitor();
  }, []);

  return (
    <GridItem
      w="100%"
      h={{ base: "80px", lg: "300px" }}
      colSpan={{ base: 8, lg: 4 }}
    >
      <VStack
        align={{ base: "center", lg: "stretch" }}
        marginTop={{ base: "0", lg: "60px" }}
        marginLeft={{ base: "0", lg: "50px" }}
      >
        <Box w={{ base: "100px", lg: "220px" }} paddingBottom={"10px"}>
          <Image src={imgLogoMd} alt="Logo" w="100%" />
          <HStack>
            <Text fontSize={{ base: "xs", lg: "md" }} textAlign={"justify"}>
              {visitor?.count} Visitor
            </Text>
          </HStack>
        </Box>
      </VStack>
    </GridItem>
  );
};

If you want to integrate this into an existing website, I suggest to have a look here. You would need to do something like this for your component to show up:
const domNode = document.getElementById('footer');
const root = createRoot(domNode);
root.render(<Footer />);

This is what turns JSX into actual HTML. Without that, nothing will show up at all.
I did not test the code, so there might be some errors left.

still get this error "Cannot find name 'response'. Did you mean 'Response'?ts(2552)"

Sorry, that was my bad. I corrected my code, specifically the result of the await statement needs to be stored. It was actually fine in your code.
